# NSWindow display and setViewsNeedDisplay

Tags: cocoa

In `NSWindow` class I found, among others, two methods: `display` and `setViewsNeedDisplay:`. But I don't know the difference between these two methods. Although  documentation says: "You rarely need to invoke this method", I need to call one of these to update window's `contentView`. The problem that the I don't know which method to call. Maybe somebody can tell me difference between those 2 methods? 
Thanks.

*P.S.*`contentView` of window is my custom view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both windows and views, `display` method redraws the object immediately, and `setViewsNeedDisplay:`/`setNeedsDisplay:` set a flag that redraw is needed while the actual redraw will happen later. Repeatedly displaying a view is expensive, repeatedly marking it for display is very cheap.

Most of the time you need to call `setNeedsDisplay:` on the view you want to be redrawn. Or even `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` to mark only a part of it, not the whole view. So if all you need is contentView to be redrawn, call `[[window contentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES]` and that will be it.

In rare cases, for example, before invoking a blocking API call or displaying a modal alert, you will have to call `display` on the view instead, otherwise the call will block for a long time before redraw happens.

In even more rare cases, you will have to call `display` on the window, for example, if you tinkered with areas outside content view, like title and borders.

And you almost never need `-[NSWindow setViewsNeedDisplay:]`. I don't know an example when one needs it.